# How do I keep Counter() from splitting up my strings?

Tags: python, list, counter

So I am using the Counter() method from collections and trying to read in a column from a data frame to get the counts of particular countries. The problem is that the Counter() splits the strings that are read in into the individual letters. For example I am running something similar to this:

```
from collections import Counter 

country_counter = Counter()

my_list = ['US', 'US', 'Mex', 'Can', 'US', 'Can']

for x in my_list:
    country_counter.update(x)
```

This gives an output of:

```
Counter({'U': 3, 'S': 3, 'M': 1, 'e': 1, 'x': 1, 'C': 2, 'a': 2, 'n': 2})
```

But I am trying for:

```
Counter({'US': 3, 'Can': 2, 'Mex': 1})
```

Any help on how to correct this? Should I even be using Counter() or is there a more efficient method?

Comment: Replace `country_counter.update(x)` with `country_counter.update((x,))`.

Comment: You can skip the loop altogether: `countery_counter.update(my_list)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply give the list as an input to the `Counter`. What currently you are doing is iterating over each string and giving it as an input and thus the Counter considers individual letters if you give it an input.

```
>>> from collections import Counter 
>>> my_list = ['US', 'US', 'Mex', 'Can', 'US', 'Can']
>>> c=Counter(my_list)
>>> c
Counter({'US': 3, 'Can': 2, 'Mex': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks! I also think I was running into trouble trying to pass the df column into the counter through a loop. Using your tip after creating an empty list and appending the items of the column worked.